# Error when fitting a beta distribution: the function mle failed to estimate the parameters with error code 100

Tags: r, distribution, fitdistrplus

I'm trying to use `fitdist ()` function from the `fitdistrplus` package to fit my data to different distributions. Let's say that my data looks like:

```
x = c (1.300000, 1.220000, 1.160000, 1.300000, 1.380000, 1.240000,
1.150000, 1.180000, 1.350000, 1.290000, 1.150000, 1.240000,
1.150000, 1.120000, 1.260000, 1.120000, 1.460000, 1.310000,
1.270000, 1.260000, 1.270000, 1.180000, 1.290000, 1.120000,
1.310000, 1.120000, 1.220000, 1.160000, 1.460000, 1.410000,
1.250000, 1.200000, 1.180000, 1.830000, 1.670000, 1.130000,
1.150000, 1.170000, 1.190000, 1.380000, 1.160000, 1.120000,
1.280000, 1.180000, 1.170000, 1.410000, 1.550000, 1.170000,
1.298701, 1.123595, 1.098901, 1.123595, 1.110000, 1.420000,
1.360000, 1.290000, 1.230000, 1.270000, 1.190000, 1.180000,
1.298701, 1.136364, 1.098901, 1.123595, 1.316900, 1.281800,
1.239400, 1.216989, 1.785077, 1.250800, 1.370000)
```

Next, if i run `fitdist (x, "gamma")` everything is fine, but if I use `fitdist (x, "beta")` instead I get the following error:

```
Error in start.arg.default(data10, distr = distname) : 
  values must be in [0-1] to fit a beta distribution
```

Ok, so I'm not native english but as far as I understand this method requires data to be in the range [0,1], so I scale it by using `x_scaled = (x-min(x))/max(x)`. This gives me a vector with values in that range that perfectly correlates the original vector `x`.

Because of `x_scaled` is of `class matrix`, I convert into a numeric vector using `as.numeric()`. And then fit the model with `fitdist(x_scale,"beta")`.

This time I get the following error:

```
Error in fitdist(x_scale, "beta") : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, with the error code 100
```

So after that I've been doing some search engine queries but I don't find anything useful. Does anybody ave an idea of whats going on wrong here? Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By reading into the source code, it can be found that the default estimation method of `fitdist` is `mle`, which will call `mledist` from the same package, which will construct a negative log-likelihood for the distribution you have chosen and use `optim` or `constrOptim` to numerically minimize it. If there is anything wrong with the numerical optimization process, you get the error message you've got.

It seems like the error occurs because when `x_scaled` contains 0 or 1, there will be some problem in calculating the negative log-likelihood for beta distribution, so the numerical optimization method will simply broke. One dirty trick is to let `x_scaled <- (x - min(x) + 0.001) / (max(x) - min(x) + 0.002)`, so there is no 0 nor 1 in `x_scaled`, and `fitdist` will work.

Comment: Pretty nice approach! You're a hacker!! That solved the problem, thank you very much! :)